# why hibernate not set foreign key in the owner side of OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, jackson

I have 2 Entities, Hospital and Department, Department reference its hospital by hospital_id in it.

```
@Entity
public class Hospital {
    ...
    private Set<Department> departments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hospital", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Department> getDepartments() {
        return departments;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Department {
    ...
    private Hospital hospital;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hospital_id")
    public Hospital getHospital() {
        return hospital;
    }
}
```

I use Rest API to create instance of Entities:

```
@RequestMapping("/create")
@ResponseBody Hospital create(@RequestBody Hospital hospital){
    hospital = hospitalService.save(hospital);

    return hospital;
}
```

I post json payload to create a Hospital:

```
{"name":"t-hospital", "departments":[{"name": "department1"}]}
```

Since I use SpringBoot, Jackson will auto parse the json payload into Java Object, here its Hospital and Departments in it.

While after I save the hospital, I found the foreign key: 'hospital_id' in department is not set.

Why is this and if possible, how can I make the foreign key set when I save the hospital object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always create an association in owner side before persisting an entity because owner side is responsible for creating relationships.

Modify your code as below (Contains Java 8 Code):

```
@RequestMapping("/create")
@ResponseBody Hospital create(@RequestBody Hospital hospital){

    hospital.getDepartments().forEach(department->department.setHospital(hospital));
    hospital = hospitalService.save(hospital);

    return hospital;
}
```

You may face a new problem when converting entity to json because Jackson serializes related entities recursively and you'll get StackOverflow Error. To resolve this issue add `@JsonManagedReference` along with `@OneToMany` annotation and `@JsonBackReference` along with `@ManyToOne` annotation.

**Note:**`@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` available in new version of Jackson

Comment: Be careful, and watch to not have @JoinColumn(..., "insertable = false, updatable = false"), that would mean not to insert or update that column, and "hospital_id" would not be set.

Answer (score 0):

Remove cascade from `@ManyToOne` annotation and add `nullable = false` to `JoinColumn`

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "hospital_id", nullable = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch type as lazy. In joining column, make it not null.

```
@Entity
public class Hospital {
    ...
    private Set<Department> departments;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "hospital")
    public Set<Department> getDepartments() {
        return departments;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Department {
    ...
    private Hospital hospital;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hospital_id", nullable = false)
    public Hospital getHospital() {
        return hospital;
    }
}
```

### Resource link:

[Hibernate – One-to-Many example (Annotation)](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)